# retrieving multiparts/ form data from angular to laravel php RESTfull api

Tags: php, angular, laravel, ionic-framework

I have an app developed using ionic angular and I want to upload files and send to laravel php
here I what I have done but this not working.

Here is my submit form in ionic angular :

```
 async submitForm(){
    let options = {headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
      'Content-Type': 'multi-part/formdata',
     })  };
    let formData= new FormData();
    formData.append("photo",this.file, this.file.name);
    // console.log(formData)
    this.http.post<any>(this.env.API_URL + 'auth/form', formData, options).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.alertService.presentToast("تم رفع الملفات بنجاح");
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    )
```

laravel side:

```
public function apistore(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user()->id;
        $this->validate($request, [
            // 'photo' => 'required',
        ]);
        $image = $request->{'photo'};
        if($image->hasFile('photo'))
        {
            $file=$image->file('photo');
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $picture = date('His').'-'.$filename;
            $file->move(public_path().'/attach/images', $picture);  
        }
        $attachments= new attachments();
        $attachments->filename=$image;
        $attachments->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $attachments->take_image = $request->{'take_image'};
        $attachments->save();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $attachments->toArray(),
            'message' => 'Data updated'
        ]);
    }
```

I usually retrieve data from ionic like this and it is working

```
    $job_info->job = $request->{'job_info.job'};
```

Comment: what is the output of the $request::all() in laravel controller function?

Comment: If you dd($request) in controller, can you see the photo in request?

Comment: I think the issue with the header value. it should be multipart/form-data not multi-part/formdata

Comment: No I got this error 404 OK","error"

Comment: Sachin I have edit it and I got this error (  500 error :{"message":"Call to a member function hasFile() on null" )

Comment: Use `FileTransfer` Plugin.

Comment: I will try it now